# can't access session data after redirect

Tags: session, symfony, symfony-2.1

I use FOSUserBundle to register new users.

User answers few questions which are saved to the session. If the answers are correct the user is redirected to register action. After register the user is redirected to the finalAction.
In the finalAction I can't access the data from the session, but when I reload the page, the data is there.

Does anyone knows whats wrong?

A part of code in my registerAction()

```
      $formHandler = $this->container->get('project_user.form.handler.registration');
        $process = $formHandler->process(false);
        if ($process)
        {

            $user = $form->getData();
            $url = $this->container->get('router')->generate('project_user_check_register', array(
                'url' => urlencode($pLink . '?from_register=1')
            ));

            $response = new RedirectResponse($url, 301);

            $authenticate = $this->authenticateUser($user, $response, true);

            return $authenticate;
        }
```

here is the authenticateUser method

```
protected function authenticateUser(UserInterface $user, Response $response, $registration = false)
    {         
        $expires = time() + 31536000;
        $secret = $this->container->getParameter('secret');
        $userClass = get_class($user);

        $value = base64_encode(implode(':', array(
            $userClass,
            base64_encode($user->getUsername()),
            $expires,  
            hash('sha256', $userClass.$user->getUsername().$expires.$user->getPassword().$secret)
            )));

        $response->headers->setCookie(
            new Cookie(
                'REMEMBERME',
                $value,
                $expires
            )
        );   

        try
        {
            $this->container->get('fos_user.security.login_manager')->loginUser(
                    $this->container->getParameter('fos_user.firewall_name'), $user, $response);

        }
        catch (AccountStatusException $ex)
        {
            // We simply do not authenticate users which do not pass the user
            // checker (not enabled, expired, etc.).
        }

        if($registration)
        {
            /*
             * remove the recommendation cookie
             */
            if ($this->container->get('request')->cookies->get('recommendCookie'))
            {
                $cookie = new Cookie('recommendCookie', '_______', time() - 100);

                $response->headers->setCookie($cookie);
            }            

        }
        return $response;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us some revelant part of code?

Comment: there is no reference to session in you code, we can't really help. where are you using it?